# Adding a panel from a method to a frame

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, jpanel

I didn't really know how else to phrase that but essentially:

-I have a few separate "pieces" that I am trying to add onto a master frame; to keep the code from getting unwieldy I have each "piece" be its own class.

-I'm getting stuck on adding the panells onto the master frame, because the classes themselves aren't panels, rather the method of the class creates the panel, which creates issues that I don't know how to solve.

PIECE (works on its own when I have it make a dialog instead of be a panel):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class PieceThing3 extends JPanel //<switched from JDialog
{
    //set up variables here


private ActionListener pieceAction = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
    {
        // Action Listener (this also works)
    }
};

private void createPiece()
{
    //setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    //setLocationByPlatform(true);
    // the above are commented out when I switch from dialog to panel

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

    //something that uses pieceAction is here

    //two buttons, b and s, with action listeners are here

    contentPane.add(b);
    contentPane.add(s);
    add(contentPane);
    //pack();
       //again, commented out to switch from dialog
    setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("hi I'm done");
      //just to check and make sure it's done
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new PieceThing3().createPiece();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Sorry that is very vague, but the intricacies are not as important as the general idea - it works perfectly when I have it create its own dialog box, but now I am trying to get it to make a panel within a master code, below:

MASTER:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CollectGUI extends JFrame{


private void createDialog(){
    this.setSize(2000,1000);
    this.setLocation(0,0);
    this.setTitle("TITLE");


    PieceThing3 pt = new PieceThing3();
    //HERE, if I do pt.main(null); while it is in "dialog mode" (rather than panel) it pops up a dialog box and everything is hunky dory. But I don't know how to get it to add the method as a panel.

   this.add(pt.main(null));
   //this gives an error

   this.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new CollectGUI().createDialog();
}

}
```

As I said in the comments, if I just do pt.main(null) when pt is set to make a dialog, it does it, but if I try to add pt.main(null) as a panel it throws an error. Can anybody give me some insight on how to add a method of a class rather than a class? I'm pretty stumped.

THANK YOU!!

Comment: The error I get is "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (void)" which I understand what that means in essence but don't really know how to fix! Thank you!

Comment: Your code makes absolutely no-sense. `this.add(pt.main(null));` should probably be replaced by `pt.createPiece(); this.add(pt);`. Btw, you create an `ActionListener` which is not added as a listener to anything, so it will never get invoked

Comment: I do use the ActionListener, I just took it out before posting because what the parts do is less relevant than getting them on the main panel at the moment. The parts work fine. That replacement worked perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track working to maintain separation of concerns and implement your gui in a number of distinct components.  Try something like this:

Panel1

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1() {
        this.add(new JLabel("This is panel 1"));
    }

}
```

Panel2

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    public Panel2() {
        this.add(new JLabel("This is panel 2"));
    }

}
```

JFrame

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.yaorma.example.jframe.panel.panel1.Panel1;
import org.yaorma.example.jframe.panel.panel2.Panel2;

public class ExampleJFrame extends JFrame {

    public ExampleJFrame() {
        super("Example JFrame Application");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Panel1 pan1 = new Panel1();
        Panel2 pan2 = new Panel2();
        this.add(pan1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(pan2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

main:

```
public class ExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ExampleJFrame();
    }

}
```

EDIT:
Here's a Panel1 with a little more content.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.yaorma.example.action.sayhello.SayHelloAction;

public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    //
    // instance variables
    //

    private JButton pressMeButton;

    //
    // constructor
    //

    public Panel1() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(new JLabel("This is panel 1"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.initPressMeButton();
    }

    //
    // button
    //

    private void initPressMeButton() {
        this.pressMeButton = new JButton("Press Me");
        this.pressMeButton.addActionListener(new PressMeButtonActionListener());
        this.add(pressMeButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    //
    // method to get the parent jframe
    //

    private JFrame getParentJFrame() {
        Container con = this;
        while(con != null) {
            con = con.getParent();
            if(con instanceof JFrame) {
                return (JFrame)con;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //
    // action listener for Press Me button
    //

    private class PressMeButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFrame jFrame = getParentJFrame();
            SayHelloAction action = new SayHelloAction(jFrame);
            action.execute();
        }

    }

}
```

Action called by button:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SayHelloAction {

    private JFrame owner;

    public SayHelloAction(JFrame owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void execute() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(owner, "Hello World");
    }

}
```

Comment: Added a Panel1 with a little more content (to the answer)